# Asynchronous File Download with Progress Bar

Tags: c#, asynchronous, progress-bar

I am attempting to have a progress bar's progress change as the `WebClient` download progress changes. This code still downloads the file yet when I call `startDownload()` the window freezes as it downloads the file. I would like for the user to be able to see the progress change as the splash screen loads. Is there any way to fix this so that the user can see the progress of `progressBar2` change?

```
private void startDownload()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://joshua-ferrara.com/luahelper/lua.syn"), @"C:\LUAHelper\Syntax Files\lua.syn");
}
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    label2.Text = "Downloaded " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "Completed";
}
```

Comment: if the window freezes it means that the person is downloading on the UI thread which translates to your code being synchronous and not asynchronous.

Comment: I'm calling `startDownload()` through a background worker running asynchronously. That shouldn't cause the window to freeze though, right?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Just a note... you don't need to calculate the percentage. `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs` has `e.ProgressPercentage` already there for you to use.

Comment: Hay David Sherret! e.ProgressPercentage always give 0 value. Do you know how to get value please....!
I assigned this as:  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage, but not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should call `startDownload()` from the UI thread. The whole idea of `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()` is that it will spawn a worker thread for you automatically without blocking the calling thread.  In `startDownload()`, you specified callbacks that modify controls which I assume were created by the UI thread.  Thus if you call `startDownload()` from a background thread it will cause problems, because a thread can only modify UI elements it created.

The way it is supposed to work is you call `startDownload()` from the UI thread, `startDownload()` as you defined it sets up event call backs that are handled by the UI thread.  It then starts the download asynchronously and returns immediately.  The UI thread will be notified when the progress changes and the code responsible for updating the progress bar control will execute on the UI thread, and there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I wouldn't be able to start the download via another async thread. All is working fine now.

Answer (score 38):

UI Thread will be freezed when you click **startDownload()**. If you don't want get form freezed, you use **startDownload()** in another thread and make progress updating in cross-threaded.
One way,

```
private void startDownload()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
          WebClient client = new WebClient();
          client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
          client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
          client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://joshua-ferrara.com/luahelper/lua.syn"), @"C:\LUAHelper\Syntax Files\lua.syn");
    });
    thread.Start();
}
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        label2.Text = "Downloaded " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    });
}
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
         label2.Text = "Completed";
    }); 
}
```

Read more multi-threading in Google like this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

-Fixed missing close ); to the bgThread declaration

Comment: MethodInvoker is not coming in my program what should i do

Comment: BeginInvoke is in the WinForms namespace. If you are using WPF you should use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: Using the above code to download the files but, i am getting unable to connect remote server error.

Comment: so what is the Syntax insted of this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class ProgressEventArgsEx
{
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public async static Task<string> DownloadStraingAsyncronous(string url, IProgress<ProgressEventArgsEx> progress)
{
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    var bytes = 0;
    var all = String.Empty;
    using (var stream = await c.OpenReadTaskAsync(url))
    {
        int total = -1;
        Int32.TryParse(c.ResponseHeaders[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength], out total);
        for (; ; )
        {
            int len = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (len == 0)
                break;
            string text = c.Encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, len);

            bytes += len;
            all += text;
            if (progress != null)
            {
                var args = new ProgressEventArgsEx();
                args.Percentage = (total <= 0 ? 0 : (100 * bytes) / total);
                progress.Report(args);
            }
        }
    }
    return all;
}
// Sample
private async void Bttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //construct Progress<T>, passing ReportProgress as the Action<T> 
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<ProgressEventArgsEx>(ReportProgress);
    await TaskLoader.DownloadStraingAsyncronous(tbx.Text, progressIndicator);
}
private void ReportProgress(ProgressEventArgsEx args)
{
    this.statusText.Text = args.Text + " " + args.Percentage;
}
```

Comment: Kudos for providing the only answer that uses `IProgress(Of T)`. +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe this article will lead you in the right direction http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115491-download-file-asynchronously-with-progressbar/ .

And in this MSDN Article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675.aspx discusses how "The file is downloaded on the BackgroundWorker component's worker thread, which runs the DoWork event handler. This thread starts when your code calls the RunWorkerAsync method."

Comment: I've already followed that article which led to the same issue.

Comment: Are you using your function to show download progress from the background thread? If so, you should start it in the UI thread, but hook the background worker's progress function to it. I hope that might be of some help. I'm still doing some reading pertaining the trouble you're having so hopefully I might be able to come up with another solution.