# Webclient progress will not show up in progressbar

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download a file with a webclient from a server. This works very good. But when I try to show the download progress in a progress bar, it does not give me any progress to see.

I am trying to download the file with the **DownloadFileAsync**-method to have an own thread for it all in order to prevent performance problems or freezes.

I declared the WebClient outside any subs or events:

```
private WebClient updateDownloader = new WebClient();
```

This looks like that in the **Form.Shown**-Event:

```
updateDownloader.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(UriGoesHere), PathToSave);
```

It is in a Try-Block.

I created a sub like that to show the progress to the progressbar:

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

In the **Form-Load**-Event I created the eventhandler:

```
updateDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
```

This should work in theory, but it does not, I already visited MSDN and saw some information that only some methods are working, but implementing this did not help.

It never reaches this one. What am I doing wrong? If you need some more code parts, tell me.

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459225/asynchronous-file-download-with-progress-bar). This good sample.

Comment: Mr.kto Unfortunately this did not help, because the op in this thread just had the problem with freezing, but as he fixed that, he could see the progress. I think, my code is pretty much the same, but I cannot find the error. I think, I am just totally blind because I am dealing with that now since an hour.

Comment: What is the file size? is it too big? or have slow connection? Can you try this label1.Text = e.BytesReceived.ToString(); in your ProgressChanged event and see if you get any result!

Comment: I solved it already. I just set the event handler at the wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify your 'Form Shown' Event to be:

```
Application.DoEvents();
updateDownloader.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(UriGoesHere), PathToSave);
```

Comment: Application.DoEvents is not a good solution. I posted the solution in a comment above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the progresbar from the main UI thread. You can't update UI from other thread directly.

Comment: I already tried to do this with invoking, but it did not work as well.
You know, how I could do it?