# Threaded DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, downloadfileasync

I might be very stupid but how to solve the following?
When I want to download many files I use a list of links and threaded WebClient.DownloadFileAsync. But I want my UI to be updated (ProgressBar) during the process so I used **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459441)** to partially solve the problem.

But when I apply this part of code

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Delegate MethodInvoker)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            thebar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        });
    }
```

I get the " 'System.Delegate' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' " error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to run a delegate on the WPF UI thread.

Comment: Okay then, this helped with the first problem. Many thanks, even though I couldn't give it a try because the second one still remains.

Comment: Use the `Action` delegate.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of delegates & anonymous methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx

Comment: Specifically, you need to cast the anonymous method to a compatible delegate type.

Comment: Heck, still nothing. I understand what's on that MSDN page but don't catch it. I'm not a professional in all this (used to code in my free time), so I would be very pleased if you helped me getting over that so-called anonymous method.

Comment: You can create an anonymous method and convert it to the `Action` delegate type by writing `new Action(delegate { ... })` (a regular cast would also work)