# Tracking download progress of the Redmine API 'GetObjects' call

Tags: c#, async-await, redmine-api

I would like to know if there is ANY way to track the downloading progress of the following call to the redmine servers:

```
List<Issue> GetTickets = new List<Issue>();
var parameters = new NameValueCollection { { "include", "journals" }, { "project_id", "62" }, { "updated_on", entireWeek } };

GetTickets = await RedmineAdmin.GetObjectsAsync<Issue>(parameters);//Here
```

I've seen the documentation on GitHub [Async Example](https://github.com/zapadi/redmine-net-api/wiki/Download-file), but I haven't found anything helpful.

I want to display the progress of the call on a progress bar if that is possible somewhere along the lines when I figure everything out.

Comment: Are you trying to display progress of file download or?

Comment: @AleksandarPavić Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: Try looking here since it's Microsoft's C# download standard stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459225/asynchronous-file-download-with-progress-bar