# Mechanism to check whether file downloaded successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to check whether file downloaded successfully. My action result is returning `CheckedFileStreamResult`. However the`OnResultExecutedhandler` is executed even before the file download is complete.

I am using the following proposed solution in my program:

```
public class CheckedFileStreamResult : FileStreamResult
    {
        public CheckedFileStreamResult(FileStream stream, string contentType): base(stream, contentType)
        {
            DownloadCompleted = false;
        }

        public bool DownloadCompleted { get; set; }

        protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            var outputStream = response.OutputStream;
            response.BufferOutput = false;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\ABC.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
                var count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                while (count != 0 && response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    response.Flush();
                    count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                }
                DownloadCompleted = response.IsClientConnected;
            }
        }
        private const int _bufferSize = 0x200;
    }
```

Using this mechanism I am unable to achieve the desired effect. The `OnResultExecuted` handler is executed before the file is fully downloaded and `DownloadCompleted` flag gives a false impression. Please guide me how to proceed.

Comment: Please refer the following Url. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470127/detect-if-file-was-downloaded-successfully-in-asp-net-mvc-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470127/detect-if-file-was-downloaded-successfully-in-asp-net-mvc-5)