# downloading a large video with Dio download causes out of memory

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to make a flutter app with downloading videos functionality from a url and videos are expected to be large (1 to 2 hours of 720p atleast).

I used Dio for this but it tries to store the complete video in RAM which causes the out of memory error. This is the code I used.

Any workarounds? or better solutions?

```
 Dio dio = Dio();
  dio
      .download(
        url,
        filePathAndName,
        onReceiveProgress: (count, total) {
       
          progressStream.add(count / total);
        },
      )
      .asStream()
      .listen((event) {
       
      })
      .onDone(() {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Video downloaded");
       
      });
```

After a while it gives this exception :
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading large pdf files in a Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839935/downloading-large-pdf-files-in-a-flutter-app)

Comment: tried that @RishabhDeepSingh wasn't able to store it in the path I want. Can you help me with that. Actually I am handling downloads for the first times.

Comment: what is the size of the video you downloading?

Comment: try to use Isolate

Comment: it may be around 200mb to 1GB max.

Comment: @MadMan 
The thing is I want to use the download progress and add it to a stream for a streambuilder to use it. 
Is it possible to add to a stream in the main isolate from the new isolate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a large file, I think it would be better to download your file using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin which also supports notifications and background mode

#### Init flutter downloader

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
  debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
);
```

#### Handle isolates

Important note: your UI is rendered in the main isolate, while download events come from a background isolate (in other words, codes in callback are run in the background isolate), so you have to handle the communication between two isolates. For example:

```
ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
    _port.listen((dynamic data) {
        String id = data[0];
        DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
        int progress = data[2];
        setState((){ });
    });

    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
}

@override
void dispose() {
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
    super.dispose();
}

static void downloadCallback(String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
    final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
    send.send([id, status, progress]);
}
```

#### Download the file

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I tried first. But it gave this error while building.
app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:20: error: package vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader does not exist
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderPlugin());
                                                                  ^

So i move forward without using that.

Comment: @keval I'm using it in a production project and it's fine, I think the error says that it's not completely imported to your project, try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`, it will be ok.

Comment: I tried that but gives the same error. Can you tell me what version of the plugin are you using.

Comment: I'm using last version. 1.6.1

Comment: I am using the same. The readme mentions no additional configuration is required for android. Is there anything you did in the android part?

Comment: i didn't change anything, have you tried testing it on a different device?

Comment: I reinstalled flutter and it worked. but I am still stuck
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778000/flutter-downloader-download-huge-video-to-application-directory-with-progress

Comment: I have the same problem with flutter_downloader. I've reinstalled the flutter and nothing changed. Flutter 3.3.6 and downloader 1.8.4