# Download file using HttpClient with ProgressBar

Tags: c#

Hello I'm just learning how to download file using httpclient.
Can anybody help me update my progressbar?
The download is working but not the progressbar.

My code for progressbar isnt't working it's not updating

```
async Task<string> GetWebSource(string url, string outputpath)
    {
        int count = 0;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback);
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = await Task.Run(() => (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url));
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36";
     
            string output = Path.Combine(outputpath, GetFilenameFromUrl(url));

            using (var httpWebResponse = await Task.Run(() => request.GetResponseAsync()))
            {
                using (var file = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(file));

                    count++;
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)(count / (double)httpWebResponse.ContentLength * 100);
                }
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                request.Abort();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: In your code your count will just ends with 1. maybe you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459225/asynchronous-file-download-with-progress-bar

Comment: Alright I will update the await.
Thank you I'll check that link

Comment: Please never write `catch (Exception) { }`. You should even avoid `catch (Exception) { ... }`.

Comment: Alright i removed the exception.

Comment: Is it really good to use httpwebrequest? 
because my progressbar is working if I use webclient. I can easily call progress

Comment: @enigmativity *alright I removed the exception* - `catch { }` lol

Comment: *Is it really good to use httpwebrequest?* - Microsoft says "don't use httpwebrequest" - don't know how much clearer you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft recommend you [don't use HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netcore-3.1) for new development; use HttpClient instead.

When you use HttpClient you can get progress like this: [Progress bar with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient) - essentially to read the stream yourself gradually and calculate how far you've read compared to the content length declared in the header. I'd probably use Bruno's answer

Comment: Wow this is a good start for me. because I just tried today using httpwebrequest.
I'm gonna explore it

Comment: should I still use using Buffer? or Copy.To?

Comment: All the examples in the linked question are a little... well.. obscure

Comment: I thought the main answer was ok; get the stream, get the header, read the stream and keep track of where you are ?

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah that part is fine, I just think there is a world of weirdness in those answers.

Comment: Might be a good opportunity to add your own non-weird one then!

Comment: @zackmark15 I didn't see you using Buffer and the answers given use copyto(async) themselves to achieve it he notion of "read so far divided by total to read equals progress" so I'm not sure what you mean by "you" using it?

Comment: @CaiusJard I dindn't mean by this thread. I mean from the give link by Ryu

Comment: I'm really confused why you commented on this answer, then - did you mean to comment on the question, with an @Ryu ?