# Progress of http request .Core

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, .net-core, restsharp

I'm using HTTP request to download a file from a specific server (Video Recorder of cameras).

This Video Recorder provides API to download a specific file using HTTP POST and body with the wanted parameters.

I'm preforming the call and after a while getting the response with the bytes of the video.
But this takes time - in relation to the network and file size.

I would like to get a progress on this request.

The Video Recorder provides also a WebUI that shows a progress bar while downloading - so I guess it is possible.

I would like also in my code to see that progress and act accordingly.

I'm using `RestSharp` for requests, but can have any other solution too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous File Download with Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459225/asynchronous-file-download-with-progress-bar)

Comment: No.. Because i don't get a file.. I have my API - http://........./download. should be called by POST with a XML in the body. I don't have a file URI that i can write to download.

Comment: Did you see https://restsharp.dev/usage/files.html?

Comment: Yes. Of course. but again the `ResponseWriter` callback being called only once. And then the `CopyTo` function hangs till the end.